# Save As PDF on Microsoft Word 2007 isn't embedding the fonts

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, embedded-fonts

When i use internal Word "Save As" PDF it never embed the font. When i use PDF Creator it works ok, but then i lose the bookmarks and cross references.

I'm using Windows 7, when i go to the font folder, the font i'm using "Font Embeddability" property is listed as "Editable", which i believe should be enough to embed.

If i set "Bitmap text when fonts may not be embedded" it displays the pdf correctly, but i cant copy the text.

Comment: I know this doesn't address the Word Save as PDF problem, but if you want the fonts to be embedded and have bookmarks and links, you could try http://www.libreoffice.org.  Before Microsoft put PDF capability in Word, I used to edit in Word and publish to PDF in OpenOffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not too late to provide and answer, you can try this:

- Click the Office Button (upper left)
- Click the Word Options button (lower right, next to Exit)
- Click the Save tab.
- At the bottom, under "Preserve fidelity when sharing this document", select "Embed fonts in the file" [Note: at this point, using the dropdown, you can select the current document or all future documents]. Click OK.

Now, you're ready to publish the file as PDF:

- From the Office button, click Save As -> PDF or XPS, to open the "Publish PDF" dialog.
- Before you click the publish button, click the Options button and ensure that "Document structure tags for accessibility" is selected, and hit OK.
- Click publish, and you're done.

(Note: best practice is to ensure that you are saving the pdf on the same machine that you created the document on, otherwise the fonts may not be available at the time of PDF creation.)

Comment: This didn't work. I believe this option only applies to docx files, not pdf, where embedding should be default.

Comment: It works for me. When you say it didn't work, how did you determine that? The method I use: -Create a new Word document. -Select a non-system font, and write a few words. -Save the file as pdf. -Open the resulting pdf in Adobe Reader. -Go to File->Properties. -Open the Fonts tab. Is the font listed?

Comment: weird, the font is listed, but its not displayed correctly. It's funny that it should display correctly even if the font wasn't being embedded, because it's installed in my system. the font im using is these 4 otf: http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/schola - i believe it's just a specific bug of word + this font   - i'll just accept your answer, thanks - but i have to say that enabling font embedding on word documents have nothing to do with font embedding on pdf.

Comment: Well, you're partly correct. The method I outlined is a widely prescribed way to embed fonts in a pdf. However, I have confirmed the behavior you witnessed on my own system using the schola font you linked to. [Using the font-embedding instructions I gave, the font is included in the PDF font list, *but it is not embedded*. In fact, if it *were* embedded, it would say so in parentheses right next to the font name in that list. That is how it works with all other fonts that I embed.].

Comment: There are some fonts whose internal license restricts their "embeddability"; however, according to the Properties of the Schola font, it is not one of them. Given the fact that I am able to correctly embed this font using a 3rd party tool ([cutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/)) I would agree with you that this appears to be a Word bug. (Similar issues [have been reported by others](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/ir_information/70/)).

Comment: If you save as "ISO 19005-1 compliant" PDF, then fonts embed perfectly (there is a host of other problems though). I doubt it has anything to do with license of the font, just that this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Word only fully supports embedding for ".ttf" fonts. If your font is not in the right format, the pdf export will not work well.

To fix the problem, all you have to do is follow this simple steps:

1. Convert the font to .ttf using a converter. I used this website https://onlinefontconverter.com/.
2. Install the converted font files. You will be prompted that the font is already install, choose "yes" to replace the old installation.
3. Enjoy :)

Comment: You can use FontForge to convert it (you might need to "flatten" it first, on the CID menu).